# Insert a Node at the Tail of a Linked List

Tags: data-structures

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)

{

  Node *current=head;

   Node *new=(Node *)malloc(size0f(Node));

   new->data=data;

   while(current->next!=NULL)

{

current=current->next;

    }

    current->next=new;

    new->next=NULL;

    return head;

}
```

**Error:**

```
solution.cc: In function 'Node* Insert(Node*, int)': 
solution.cc:23:10: error: expected unqualified-id before 'new' Node *new=(Node *)malloc(size0f(Node)); ^ 
solution.cc:23:10: error: expected initializer before 'new' 
solution.cc:24:7: error: expected type-specifier before '->' token new->data=data; ^ 
solution.cc:29:22: error: expected type-specifier before ';' token current->next=new; ^ 
solution.cc:30:8: error: expected type-specifier before '->' token new->next=NULL;
```

Comment: solution.cc: In function 'Node* Insert(Node*, int)':
solution.cc:23:10: error: expected unqualified-id before 'new'
    Node *new=(Node *)malloc(size0f(Node));
          ^
solution.cc:23:10: error: expected initializer before 'new'
solution.cc:24:7: error: expected type-specifier before '->' token
    new->data=data;
       ^
solution.cc:29:22: error: expected type-specifier before ';' token
     current->next=new;
                      ^
solution.cc:30:8: error: expected type-specifier before '->' token
     new->next=NULL;
        ^

Answer (score 1):

I think `new` is a keyword and you are trying to use that as a variable name in

```
`Node *new=(Node *)malloc(size0f(Node));`
```

and subsequent code.

Try replacing it with something like `newNode`, like below

```
`Node *newNode=(Node *)malloc(size0f(Node));`
```

And then use `newNode` in subsequent code instead of `new`

Answer (score 0):

I guess @vmachan is right, you shouldn't use `new` as a variable name.

Besides, I think you were looking for `sizeof` instead of `size0f`?